# Java - Single Slash getting converted to Double Slash when saving in Linux Properties file

Tags: java, linux, properties

I'm using PropertiesConfiguration class to update the properties in the file. I've tried both 1.9 and 1.10 versions of commons-configuration. I just can't figure out, what is wrong with it,

**Please have a look at below code-**

```
PropertiesConfiguration conf = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("Updating in " + filePath);
        conf = new PropertiesConfiguration(filePath);
    } catch (ConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    System.out.println("Password going to be updated is " + pass);
    conf.setProperty(parName, pass);
    try {
        conf.save();
    } catch (ConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

In windows OS, when I tried with Eclipse it's working fine but as I've to deploy my jar in Linux OS, and there in the properties file, I always see two '\' instead of one '\' in my properties file.

Password having '\' - `XytxvyijkZ5p+DYwn4M07EWIiGXWEk9/cnQCbQiKFOYoU8LHjg0MpxaS/GYA\n2FOASlP4Yb2ekWOD8nFmRivSBA==\n`

Getting updated in Properties file as - `XytxvyijkZ5p+DYwn4M07EWIiGXWEk9/cnQCbQiKFOYoU8LHjg0MpxaS/GYA\\\\n2FOASlP4Yb2ekWOD8nFmRivSBA==\\\\n`

Comment: That's not part of the password. The `==` is the end of Base64 padding, and since `\n` is line break, you're probably saving bad data.

Comment: Did you check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50171157/update-property-file-in-java

Comment: @Kayaman That password is an encrypted password, and the problem is not \n because that will work fine. The problem is single slash '\' getting converted to two slashes '\\'.

Comment: @MukeshKeshu Yes, I checked the link, and according to oracle docs we have to use four slashes \\\\\ rather than single slash. But, the point is I tried both ways, in case of single slash it sets double slashes, and in the case of four slashes it sets it as 8 slashes.

Comment: @Kayaman If you see properly in the password that I mentioned above, there are 2 places where we have a single slash and not only \n. So, if what you are saying is true why is it getting problematic for the first occurrence of slash '\'

Comment: Well, considering the peculiar file format of Java's properties (ISO-8859-1, unicode escaped with `\uxxxx` etc.) I'm not that surprised about the slashes, but I'd expect it to behave the same on both platforms. And the `\n` after the Base64 encoding still looks strange. Which Java version are you on?

Comment: @Kayaman I'm using 1.8